# Why are there buttons on form for no apparent reason?

Tags: acumatica

I have a Form/Detail screen I've created with header and detail information.  All works well, except for some reason it's put two buttons on the header button layout:

- 'Paste Line'
- 'Reset Order'.

[image]

[image]

I have no idea whey they're there, and I can't make them invisible.  Does anyone know why they would show up, and better yet - how I get rid of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the content of your ASPX file, especially the PXDataSource section

Answer (score 1):

You can change the visibility of a button with code. I not sure if you have tried this?

Here is an example from SOOrderEntry_Extension. In most cases, you should not use RowSelected but Visibility is an exception for me because of automation steps.

```
protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
 {
    actionName.SetVisible(false);
    actionName.SetEnabled(false);
 }
```

If it was a built-in screen you could check your automation steps for that screeen